# aborting creation process with WriteRegStr

Tags: nsis

I want to add two files of my program to the registry.

```
Section -Main SE2
WriteRegStr "$INSTDIR" "Bin" "name1"
WriteRegStr "$INSTDIR" "Bin" "name2"
SectionEnd
```

By compiling the script an error at the line of the first WriteRegStr call occurs:
Error in script: "path" on line x -- aborting creation process

How can i fix it?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of [WriteRegStr](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2.16) is:

```
WriteRegStr root_key subkey key_name value
```

- `root_key` being HKLM, HKCU, etc
- `subkey` begins with `software` then a company name and / or an application name
- `keyname` is the name of a setting
- `value` is the setting content

So you are missing at least one parameter, but even if you add it, i am unsure if you are compliant with the registry path usage, it should be `software\your company\application name` (a logical path) to group all settings relevant to the application, not an installation path...